# XML Parsing within TAG in ios

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I have a XML file:

```
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="11.004661" lon="76.97364"></trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="11.005497" lon="76.97496"></trkpt>
</trkseg>
```

Here is my code:

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trkseg"])
    {
        self.tag = [[MRTRouteMapTag alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"SRC: %@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lat"]);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.workingPropertyString appendString:string];
}

//event_logo, event_name, event_venue, event_date_time, race_details, event_descriptions;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (self.tag)
    {
        NSString *trimmedString = [self.workingPropertyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        // clear the string for next time
        [self.workingPropertyString setString:@""];

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trkseg"])
        {
            [self.array addObject:self.tag];
            self.tag = nil;
            NSLog(@"Array Count ==>>>>>> %d", [self.array count]);
        }

        // Get Registered User Details
        // ------ ------- ------------
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trkpt"])
        {
            NSDictionary *attributeDict;
            NSString *imageURLString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
            self.tag.latitude = trimmedString;
            NSLog(@"race_id ==>> %@", imageURLString);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I need to parse data from **trkpt** TAG of **lat** and **lon** value. Could any one guide me to achieve this.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What did you try? Isn't this similar to your previous question?

Comment: Yes. Here i parse all the data. But dono how to parse this lat and lon value ?? Could u guide me..

Comment: Show your code and your results. Then we can help to find the errors.

Comment: Hello, i am not playing with you, I have a problem and need to solve this. Actually my query is that "I have a XML file in my local URL. That already shown in previous question. When i parse the data, get null value only. Because here no data available within the TAG<trkpt></<trkpt>. But have the data inside TAG <trkpt lat=VALUE lon=VALUE>. How can i get lat and lon value from this ??"

Comment: Why don't you just show your code?

Comment: I added my code here. Guide me to archive this..

Comment: Use this library, it makes XML parsing so much easier: https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At finally i find the solution to archive it..

Here i added my sample code..

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trkpt"])
    {
        self.tag = [[MRTRouteMapTag alloc]init];
        lat = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
        lon = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"lon"];

        tag.latitude = lat;
        tag.longitude = lon;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.workingPropertyString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (self.tag)
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trkpt"])
        {
            [self.array addObject:self.tag];
            self.tag = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**lat** and **lon** are not values, but attributes of node **trkpt**

They should be available to you at **didStartElement** like so:

```
[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
```

or

```
[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lon"];
```

This is not related to NSXMLPArser, but the XML structure itself.

Answer (score 0):

The values that you are looking for are stored in the `attributeDict` dictionary in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
   qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
      attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```